# Setting referral id to user_new method in Eventbrite API

Tags: api, eventbrite

Is it possible to add referral id to user_new method parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Eventbrite does not support referral information on that particular API method call.

Their new [OAuth2.0 workflow](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth/) will allow a "ref=YOUR_REFERRAL_CODE" flag to be included in the initial link.